# Reconstruct folder hierarchy in JSON format from MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
| itemID |   parentFolderID | folderName

     1              0           folderA
     2              1           folderB
     3              1           folderC
     4              3           folderD
     5              4           folderE
     6              5           file.txt
```

The front-end developer needs me to construct a JSON file with a hierarchy that represents the folder structure and to look like this:

```
{"name": "folderA",
 "itemID": "1",
 "children":[
       { "name": "folderB",
          "itemID": "2",
          "children": []
       },
       { "name": "folderC",
         "itemID": "3",
         "children": [
               { "name": "folderD",
                 "itemID": "4",
                 "children": [
                       {"name": "folderE",
                        "itemID": "5",
                        "children": [
                               {"name": "file.txt",
                                "itemID": "6"
                               },
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
```

I am super new to databases and python and this problem is a bit overwhelming for my skill level. I looked into CTE, but that is not available in MySql 5.6. I was also told that this job is better handled by Python than trying to do inside the database.

I've seen suggested solutions but they are either JS, R or something else. Maybe those work, but my question is for Python; there has got to be a way to get this done.

How can I take a table and convert it into JSON structure? Thank you.

Adding python data structure for MySQL query:

```
 [{'assetID': 1,
  'assetName': 'Study Name',
  'assetTypeID': 2,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': None},
 {'assetID': 2, 'assetName': '1.json', 'assetTypeID': 1, 'parentAssetID': 1},
 {'assetID': 3,
  'assetName': 'Binder-IRB',
  'assetTypeID': 2,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 1},
 {'assetID': 4,
  'assetName': 'Serverless Security Evaluation Criteria 2019.pdf',
  'assetTypeID': 1,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 1},
 {'assetID': 5,
  'assetName': '1- IRB Approvals',
  'assetTypeID': 2,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 3},
 {'assetID': 6, 'assetName': '2-ICF', 'assetTypeID': 2, 'parentAssetID': 3},
 {'assetID': 7,
  'assetName': "3-Reports",
  'assetTypeID': 2,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 3},
 {'assetID': 8,
  'assetName': 'sample resume.docx',
  'assetTypeID': 1,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 5},
 {'assetID': 9,
  'assetName': 'Inactive ICFs',
  'assetTypeID': 2,
  'assetStoreName': 'TEST TEMPLATE',
  'parentAssetID': 6}]
```

Comment: Can you query the whole table (from your example) and paste it in your question as a python datastructure? (probably a list of lists).  From that I can help you get it to the desired json format.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I added a query on some sample data. I wouldn't know in advance how deep nested folder may go or anything like that. Thank  you very much for your help. A folder has to have an empty list as "children" and if it is a file, then there should be no children. Also, assetTypeID 1 is a document, AssetTypeID 2= folder

Comment: Will the first entry always have a `None` parent?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse    The first one will likely be None, but there could be more folders at the root and they will all be `None`. This structure represents a repository of documents, and the user can add multiple documents to the root of the repository. There is a column in the table for `assetStoreName` (an asset store is effectively a repository). I added a field in the view to reflect that and updated the above output sample. What makes sense to me is to add logic that if `parentAssetID` is `None`, make it a child of `assetStoreName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using your data in a variable labelled `query`:

```
def find_and_add_child(dic, element):
    """
    Searches through the passed in dict and its children
    to find where to insert `element`. Returns True if
    inserted and False otherwise. (Recursive)
    """
    if dic['itemID'] == element['parentAssetID']:
        # This is the right parent so add the child
        dic['children'].append({
            "name": element['assetName'],
            "itemID": element['assetID'],
            "children": []
        })
        return True
    else: # Search the children to find a valid parent
        for child in dic['children']:
            if find_and_add_child(child, element):
                return True
        return False

def query_to_json(query):
    """
    Converts the passed in json as a list of dicts
    to a json object.
    """
    results = []
    for entry in query:
        if entry['parentAssetID'] == None:
            # If not parent ID
            results.append({
                "name": entry['assetName'],
                "itemID": entry['assetID'],
                "children":[]
            })
        else: # We need to find the parent
            for result in results:
                if find_and_add_child(result, entry):
                    break # Entry added so break out of this loop
    return results

import json
print(json.dumps(query_to_json(query), indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Study Name",
    "itemID": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "1.json",
        "itemID": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Binder-IRB",
        "itemID": 3,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "1- IRB Approvals",
            "itemID": 5,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "sample resume.docx",
                "itemID": 8,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "2-ICF",
            "itemID": 6,
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Inactive ICFs",
                "itemID": 9,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "3-Reports",
            "itemID": 7,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Serverless Security Evaluation Criteria 2019.pdf",
        "itemID": 4,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two dicts: the first, to actually implement the file structure; the second, to store references to each dict that makes up the first. Let's say your python data structure is `dataframe`:

```
file_structure = {}
dicts = {}
for entry in dataframe:
    # construct initial filestructure for this new entry
    new_dict = {"name": entry["assetName"], "itemID": entry["assetID"]}
    if entry["assetTypeID"] == 2:  # shorthand for checking "is this a folder"
        new_dict["children"] = []
    # assign the new entry to dicts, so we can keep track of it more easily
    dicts[itemID] = new_dict
    # add it as a child to its parent element, or make it the root if necessary
    if entry["parentAssetID"]:
        dicts[entry["parentAssetID"]]["children"].append(new_dict)
    else:
        file_structure = new_dict
```

Note that `file_structure` is what saves the actual structure, but we use `dicts` to store as many references to locations within that file structure as we need. For example, `dicts[2]` and `file_structure["children"][0]` refer to the same object in memory.

If there are multiple things with the key `None`, you might also consider making `file_structure` a *list* of dicts in the first place, instead of the single dict that it is in your example, and doing `file_structure.append(new_dict)` instead of `file_structure = new_dict`.

After all that, converting it to json is trivial:

```
import json
...
json_str = json.dumps(file_structure)
with open("hierarchy.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_str)
```